# Page Loading Painfully Slow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having issues with the speed in which my page loads.  I've run several tests and fail just about every one of them.  I've tried compressing images and whatnot to now avail.  In no way am I adept at coding.  Fairly new to it but, trying to learn.  Just a guess, but I think the painfully slow rendering of my page may be due to errors in my accordion code.  Once loaded, everything seems to be in order, however, in creating a fiddle, the accordion does not work correctly.  It also renders correctly in the 3 or 4 different editors I've tried it with.  Below you will find a link to the working page along with the code I am using for the accordion.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Link to page:  http://www.realtimehockey.net/tournaments.html

The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Del087/rb4084ef/

The CSS

```
<style type='text/css'>
    /*<![CDATA[*/
            .accordion, .accordion * {
            -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            box-sizing:border-box;

            }

            .accordion {
            overflow:hidden;
            box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
            border-radius:3px;
            width: 100%;
            background:#ffffff;
            border:.5px solid black;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            }

            /*----- Section Titles -----*/
            .accordion-section-title {
            width: 100%;
            padding:15px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            display:inline-block;
            border-bottom:2px solid #ffffff;
            background:linear-gradient(#151515, #080808);
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
            /* Type */
            font-family: patua one;
            font-color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 28px;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-style: italic;
            text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #1a1a1a;
            color:#fff;
            border: 1px solid #ffffff;
            text-indent: 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            }

            .accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
            background:linear-gradient(#ff8a28, #ff6600);
             font-family: patua one;
            font-color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-style: italic;
            text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #1a1a1a;
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
            }

            .accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
            border-bottom:none;
            }

            /*----- Section Content -----*/
            .accordion-section-content {
            padding:5px;
            display:none;
            }

            /*]]>*/
</style>
<style>
    #table-wrapper {
        position:relative;
        }
        #table-scroll {
        height:600px;
        width: auto;
        overflow:auto;  
        margin-top:5px;
        }
        #table-wrapper table { 
        width: auto; 
        float: left;
        }
        #table-wrapper table * {
        }
        #table-wrapper table thead th .text {
        position:absolute;   
        top:-20px;
        z-index:2;
        height:20px;
        width:auto;
        }
</style>
```

Java Script

```
 <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
            $(function(){
            $(document).ready(function() {
            function close_accordion_section() {
                $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
                $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
            }

            $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
                // Grab current anchor value
                var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

                if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
                    close_accordion_section();
                }else {
                    close_accordion_section();

                    // Add active class to section title
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    // Open up the hidden content panel
                    $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open');
                }

                e.preventDefault();
            });
            });
            });//]]>  


</script>
```

The HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1"><img alt=""
        border="0" height="35" src=
        "http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHAccordionLogo3_zpszspfxeev.png"
        width="40"> ALL TOURNAMENTS</a>

        <div class="accordion-section-content" id="accordion-1">
            <div id="table-wrapper">
                <div id="table-scroll">
                    <iframe frameborder="0" height="900" scrolling="no"
                    src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=704B9036DA9EF5A7&resid=704B9036DA9EF5A7%214259&authkey=AHPRSPlWZMfMr-g&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&Item='Sheet1'!A1%3AF83&wdHideGridlines=True"
                    width="695"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-->

        <div class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title" href=
            "#accordion-2"><img alt="" border="0" height="35" src=
            "http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHAccordionLogo3_zpszspfxeev.png"
            width="40"> OneHockey TOURNAMENTS</a>

            <div class="accordion-section-content" id="accordion-2">
                <div id="table-wrapper">
                    <div id="table-scroll">
                        <iframe frameborder="0" height="796" scrolling="no"
                        src=
                        "https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=704B9036DA9EF5A7&resid=704B9036DA9EF5A7%214294&authkey=AHlomnY6QBEDbNg&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&Item='Sheet1'!A1%3AF39&wdHideGridlines=True"
                        width="695"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-->

        <div class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title" href=
            "#accordion-3"><img alt="" border="0" height="35" src=
            "http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHAccordionLogo3_zpszspfxeev.png"
            width="40"> NST TOURNAMENTS</a>

            <div class="accordion-section-content" id="accordion-3">
                <iframe frameborder="0" height="359" scrolling="no" src=
                "https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=704B9036DA9EF5A7&resid=704B9036DA9EF5A7%214254&authkey=APKpBhWADrxGjJc&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&Item='Sheet1'!A1%3AF17&wdHideGridlines=True"
                width="695"></iframe>
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-->

        <div class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title" href=
            "#accordion-4"><img alt="" border="0" height="35" src=
            "http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHAccordionLogo3_zpszspfxeev.png"
            width="40"> CanLan TOURNAMENTS</a>

            <div class="accordion-section-content" id="accordion-4">
                <iframe frameborder="0" height="630" scrolling="no" src=
                "https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=704B9036DA9EF5A7&resid=704B9036DA9EF5A7%214256&authkey=ADHo6NDfwBXvj5k&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&Item='Sheet1'!A1%3AF36&wdHideGridlines=True"
                width="695"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
    </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
</div><!--end .accordion-->
```

Comment: Bad webhosting. This 271kB image takes ages to load: https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/gamepostpictures/teamPicThumb115230-28368-10b8qqu.png

Comment: This has nothing to do with your code, this is webhosting issue. It is likely you are on a shared server and one of the sites (or more, or all) of them are generating a lot of traffic. Other options might be that the hosting is just .. well ... bad. I am not sure what you pay for it, but often cheap hosting can result into this. I ran a test. I tell you, it took more than a minute to render, and since you prolly do every minute an ajax update every minute i guess... oof

Comment: You are including "normalize.css" and "result-light.css" but they are not in the specified location. (http://www.realtimehockey.net/css/normalize.css) and (http://www.realtimehockey.net/css/result-light.css). This can slow down the site a lot.

Comment: it cant find it, won't load... that won't decrease the load time. It just takes time to find it, but multiple proces can be run at the same time, i think, although I doubt he loads it asynchronous

Comment: Thanks very much to all.  I never even thought about a hosting issue because it seems every other page loads fine and probably has more content.  @wazaaaap as I mentioned, I'm not an adept by any means so, what I need to do to amend the locations?  Appreciate the help.

Comment: If the site looks good already, you probably don't need those files, so you can remove the reference to those files. Or if those files are needed for the site to look as it should, you can download them (search on google).

Comment: @wazaaap That's exactly what I did and I it works fine now.  I was using Excel html in this accordion before and I think that was "left over".  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to test something like this is one of the many web page loading tools available.  I ran it through webpagetest.org, and got the results here: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150628_8Y_SAT/

This is not a single image problem, there seems to be a lot of loading time issues, and the page is loading a *lot* of stuff.

Also, as @wazaaaap says above, there are css files missing, which is blocking concurrent connections.

Take a look at the test results and you can see what's taking up your load time.

Comment: thanks for your input.  I did run the page through that same test and, as you might guess, I got the same result.  As I mentioned in my original post, I ran tests on several different sites and all resulted in images being the majority of the issue.  I've tried to resize and compress to no avail.  I haven't thought about a hosting issue because every other page seems to load just fine.  Again, I appreciate your assistance.